# Is it possible to specify fetchgraph/loadgraph in SpringDataJpa @QueryHint annotation

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa, query-hints

Is it possible somehow to specify the `javax.persistence.fetchgraph` or `javax.persistence.loadgraph` using @QueryHint in Spring Data Jpa?

I have an entity graph

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "shop_with_all_associations",
        includeAllAttributes = true
)
public class Shop {    
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And the corresponding method in the repository

```
@Repository
public interface ShopRepository extends JpaRepository<Shop, Integer> {
    @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.fetchgraph", value = "shop_with_all_associations")})
    List<Shop> getAllWithQueryHintBy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.
You can check your log and see the next warning when calling the method

```
o.h.q.internal.AbstractProducedQuery     : The javax.persistence.fetchgraph hint was set, but the value was not an EntityGraph!
```

And in the AbstractProducedQuery class, the next code section shows, that only instances of `RootGraph` could be treated as EntityGraph. But our `@QueryHint` allow to pass only String as value.

```
else if ( HINT_FETCHGRAPH.equals( hintName ) || HINT_LOADGRAPH.equals( hintName ) ) {
                if ( value instanceof RootGraph ) {
                    applyGraph( (RootGraph) value, GraphSemantic.fromJpaHintName( hintName ) );
                    applyEntityGraphQueryHint( new EntityGraphQueryHint( hintName, (RootGraphImpl) value ) );
                }
                else {
                    MSG_LOGGER.warnf( "The %s hint was set, but the value was not an EntityGraph!", hintName );
                }
                applied = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it through `@QueryHint` you use the `@EntityGraph` annotation.

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph

```
public interface GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<GroupInfo, String> {

  @EntityGraph(value = "GroupInfo.detail", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
  GroupInfo getByGroupName(String name);

}
```